# Vue.js watching deep properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to watch properties on a `vue.js` object, but i'm not getting the result that i want, my code is the following:

```
var vueTable = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-table',
    data: {
        filters: {},
    },
    watch: {
        filters: {
            handler: function () {
                console.log('watched');
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a `v-model` on an input like so:

```
<input class="form-control" v-model="filters.name">
```

Now when the page loads it logs `watched` in the console just once, whenever i change the input it doesn't log anything.

Yet when i put `vueTable.filters = {name: 'something'};` after the table initalization it will trigger on every change.

Is this unexpected behaviour? or do we have to define all our properties in order for them to be watched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation covers this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

By starting with an empty object and setting `v-model` to `filters.name`, you end up adding a property dynamically. The best approach in this case would be to initialize the property in the data. It doesn't have to have a value.

```
data: {
    filters: { name: null },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something with the looks of this

`this.$set(this.filters, 'name', "")`

Using $set
(as described in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) the observable will be correctly added

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `filter` object initialization in `data` property into the `created` [Vue lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

```js
var vueTable = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-table',
    // If you attach filters at this point in time
    // the watcher will work normally.
    created: function () {
        this.$data.filters = {
            filter_one: null,
            filter_two: null
        };
    },
    data: {
        filters: null,
    },
    watch: {
        filters: {
            handler: function (newValue) {
                // Here you will get the entire filter object 
                // if some property changes.
                console.dir(newValue);
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
}
```