# Vue Watch not triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to use vue watch methods but it doesn't seem to trigger for some objects even with `deep:true`.

In my component, I recieve an array as a prop that are the fields to create
the following forms.
I can build the forms and dynamicly bind them to an object called `crudModelCreate` and everything works fine (i see in vue dev tools and even submiting the form works according to plan)

But I have a problem trying to watch the changes in that dynamic object.

```
  <md-input v-for="(field, rowIndex) in fields" :key="field.id" v-model="crudModelCreate[field.name]" maxlength="250"></md-input>

   ...

   data() {
      return {
         state: 1, // This gets changed somewhere in the middle and changes fine
         crudModelCreate: {},
      }
   },
   ...
   watch: {
        'state': {
            handler: function(val, oldVal) {
                this.$emit("changedState", this.state);
                // this works fine
            },
        },
        'crudModelCreate': {
            handler: function(val, oldVal) {
                console.log("beep1")
                this.$emit("updatedCreate", this.crudModelCreate);
                // This doesn't work
            },
            deep: true,
            immediate: true
        },
    }
```

Comment: How are changes in your object performed?

Comment: You may have to use [`Vue.set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to update object properties, especially if adding new ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js watching deep properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760474/vue-js-watching-deep-properties)

Comment: @SuiDream v-model makes the changes on the object.
@AndreiNemes Absolutuly correct. On component.mounted i was calling an initializer function that would loop through the fields and set default value for the `crudModelCreate` variable (depending on the type of field) and i was doing it by doing `this.crudModelCreate[prop] = value;` changing this to `this.$set(this.crudModelCreate, prop, value);` makes the watch trigger.

Comment: @RoyJ , you're correct, my bad, it did have alot of similarities.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiNemes , `Vue.set` was the answer in my case.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the docs

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect **property addition or deletion**. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

Please take a look to Reactivity in Depth https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Even adding the watch by doing something with the likes of  
`this.$watch('$data.crudModelCreate', this.updated, { deep: true })`
after the values have been initialized didn't quite work. And after doing what Andrei Nemes said it worked so i guess in my use case wasn't that much of a limitation.

Comment: Actually what the docs says it's exactly the problem you were having, when you define an object on data like `crudModelCreate: {}` and later you add a properties to it like inside the watch `crudModelCreate` those new props won't be reactive, unless you assign it as `Vue.set(object, key, value)` like @Andrei Nemes correctly mentioned it and which I point you from the docs

Comment: You have no idea how long I have been looking for an answer to this.... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In certain circumstances it is possible to force a refresh by adding a key property to the child component containing a json string of the object being passed to it in v-model.

```
<Component v-model="deepObject" :key="JSON.stringify(deepObject)" />
```

Comment: This worked for my purposes. Put a watcher on the key instead of the object; worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In case you missed it, @AndreiNemes in comments section proposed to use `Vue.set()` which helped me to trigger `watch` on adding new properties into existing object in state.

More about `Vue.set()`: [Vue 2 documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 we can just use deep watch like:

```
watch(() => props.list, (newList, oldList) =>
{
   console.log('list updated');
}, { deep: true });
```