# How watch insertion into an object at VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying get a insertion into an object at Vue, but I can't...

```
data: {
    formValid: {},
    buttonIsDisabled: true,
    statusModal: 'active',
},
methods: {
    closeModal() {
        this.statusModal = ''
        this.formValid.test = "test"
    }

},
watch: {
    formValid: {
        handler(o, n) {
            console.log(o)
            console.log(n)
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

When I do 'this.formValid.test = "test"' I don't go to Watch, but if I have this object into of the formValid and I change it, in this case, I go to Watch.

Do you know how can I get this event?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: why not just make a separate variable only for this logic ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Watch not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666819/vue-watch-not-triggering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add reactive properties to an object on the fly with Vue2 like this.
You'll need to either define them in `data`:

```
data: {
    formValid: {
        test: '',
    },
    buttonIsDisabled: true,
    statusModal: 'active',
},
```

or use:
`Vue.set(this.formValid, 'test', 'test');`