# how to use Vue watch in objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am pretty new to `watch` and trying to figure out why my watch isn't triggering when accessing it as an object. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760474/vue-js-watching-deep-properties) thread, but it isn't clear to me if my problem is the same. Following is my simplified example (full example got more properties and properties with array

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model.lazy="userInfo.name"> {{userInfo.name}}
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  userInfo: {
            name: ''
  }

  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch: {
    userInfo : {
            name(oldVal, newVal){
            console.log(oldVal +" " + newVal)
      },
    },
     deep: true
  }
})
```

Link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahassan/nsx87rd3/17/)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js - How to properly watch for nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data)

Comment: Change the watcher to something like this ` watch: {
   'userInfo.name' :
        function(oldVal, newVal){
        console.log(oldVal +" " + newVal);
    },
     deep: true
  }`

Comment: thanks @Majid . It make good sense then docs. If u want Put it as answer and I will accept the answer. If possible, can u break down what it says in docs as it is hard to understand [vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch](watch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the watcher to something like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    userInfo: {
      name: "null"
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  watch: {
    "userInfo.name": function(oldVal, newVal) {
      console.log(oldVal + " " + newVal);
    }
  }
});
```

Refer to the documentation for the same [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch).
Check the last example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example in your case:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  userInfo: {
       name: 'null'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      return this.userInfo.name;
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch: {
    name(newVal, oldVal) {
      alert(newVal);
      alert(oldVal);
    }
  },
})
```